# Ctrl + shift is not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Today I upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.04 version and noticed that shortcuts commands using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> buttons are not working. It not depends on selected language, it's just ignores <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. How can I fix that?

Comment: What's the output of ```xmodmap -pk | grep -i control```?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi


 37     0xffe3 (Control_L) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group) 
 0xffe3 (Control_L) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group) 
 0xffe3 (Control_L) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group)
 0xffe3 (Control_L) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group) 
    
 105 0xffe4 (Control_R) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group) 
 0xffe4 (Control_R) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group) 
 0xffe4 (Control_R) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group)
 0xffe4 (Control_R) 
 0xfe08 (ISO_Next_Group)

Comment: So the the problem is not with the Keyboard input.Have you checked the shortcuts for changing layouts?

Comment: I used this app to check keyboard http://en.key-test.ru/. 
When I click `ctrl` it disaplays click, when I click `shift` it indicates, but not for them clicked together. I don't know what setting should I check. I just upgraded to 20.04 from my CLI and these shortcuts are not working anymore(

Comment: Why is this question closed, the supposed duplicate it points to asks for something completely different!

Answer (score 0):

Try to review the input sources settings -> Region & Language -> Input sources, maybe you have misconfigured that.
On the other way, you can use an application in order to view if the system catches the keystroke. You may want to look at something like https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/screenkey-show-key-presses-screen-ubuntu